# Regex e-mail checker not working, regex ignores the dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex e-mail checker.  Here is my code:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event)
{
  userID = $("#email").val();
    if (userID.match("[a-zA-Z\d]+\@[a-zA-Z\d]+\.[a-zA-Z\d]+"))
{
    $("#emCheck").text("Thank you for your email address!");
    $("#emCheck").css("color", "black");
  }
  else
  {
    $("#emCheck").text("Please enter a valid email.");
  }

}
```

What's odd is this seems to work for the @ sign, but not the dot.  "dennis" is not a valid e-mail, but "dennis@yahoo" is.  Why is this?  Why does the @ sign work but the dot does not?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it in regexr but it looks like it works as intended so I'm not sure if the expression is wrong. https://regexr.com/4j15a

Comment: Rewrite `"` in regex to `/`

Comment: Dominik's suggestion worked!

Comment: In JS, there are 2 ways to compile a regex object `new RegExp("---")` or just `/---/`. Also, metachars need to be escaped in the windows programming JS world, so `"\\d"` is a regex digit character. IF you use the `/--/` notation, then you don't need to escape metachars.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)